# PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got NUMBER

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm executing PL/SQL code to display the Currency Code from the Failed Reservation table. Object type and Nested Table collections are used. 
When the PL/SQL code is run, the following error is generated. The corresponding line is highlighted in the PL/SQL code section.

**Error report:**

```
ORA-06550: line 27, column 11:
PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got NUMBER
ORA-06550: line 27, column 4:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

The code is pasted below:

**DDL - Table creation:**

```
CREATE TABLE FAILEDRESERVATION
(   
    FAILEDRESERVATIONID NUMBER(18,0), 
    FK_TRANSACTIONID NUMBER(18,0), 
    DEBITRESERVATIONID NUMBER(18,0), 
    RESERVATIONTIME DATE, 
    RESERVATIONAMOUNT NUMBER(18,5), 
    CURRENCYCODE CHAR(3 BYTE), 
    AVAILABLEAMOUNT NUMBER(18,5)
);

ALTER TABLE FAILEDRESERVATION 
ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_FAILEDRESERVATION" PRIMARY KEY ("FAILEDRESERVATIONID");
```

**Object Type:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYPE type_failedreservation AS OBJECT 
(                                     
    FK_TRANSACTIONID     NUMBER(18),    
    DEBITRESERVATIONID   NUMBER(18),    
    RESERVATIONTIME      DATE,          
    RESERVATIONAMOUNT    NUMBER(18,5),  
    CURRENCYCODE         CHAR(3),       
    AVAILABLEAMOUNT      NUMBER(18,5)   
);
```

**DML:**

```
INSERT INTO FAILEDRESERVATION (FAILEDRESERVATIONID,FK_TRANSACTIONID,DEBITRESERVATIONID,RESERVATIONTIME,RESERVATIONAMOUNT,CURRENCYCODE,AVAILABLEAMOUNT) 
VALUES (289,2,1,to_date('07-MAR-16','DD-MON-RR'),20000,'USD',10000);

INSERT INTO FAILEDRESERVATION (FAILEDRESERVATIONID,FK_TRANSACTIONID,DEBITRESERVATIONID,RESERVATIONTIME,RESERVATIONAMOUNT,CURRENCYCODE,AVAILABLEAMOUNT) 
VALUES (288,1,1,to_date('01-MAR-16','DD-MON-RR'),10000,'NOK',10000);
```

**Nested Tables:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE type_failedreservation_coll as TABLE OF type_failedreservation; 

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE type_dbtrsid_coll AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

**PL/SQL Code:**

```
DECLARE    
    P_FAILEDRESERVATION APPDATA.TYPE_FAILEDRESERVATION_COLL;

    vdbtid_coll type_dbtrsid_coll := type_dbtrsid_coll();

BEGIN    
    SELECT TYPE_FAILEDRESERVATION(fk_transactionid,debitreservationid,reservationtime,reservationamount,currencycode,availableamount) 
    BULK COLLECT 
    INTO p_failedreservation                                                                                                     
    FROM failedreservation;

    -- This is line 27
    SELECT frs.debitreservationid
    INTO vdbtid_coll
    FROM TABLE(p_failedreservation) frs;


    FOR v_iterate IN vdbtid_coll.FIRST..vdbtid_coll.LAST  
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('The currency code is: '||v_iterate);  
    END LOOP;

END;
```

Why is the code generating this error ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've declared `vdbtid_coll` as a collection type, so you need to bulk collect into that too:

```
SELECT frs.debitreservationid
BULK COLLECT INTO vdbtid_coll
FROM TABLE(p_failedreservation) frs;
```

With that change:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
The currency code is: 1
The currency code is: 2
```

That's just giving you the index number in the collection though, so I don't think it's what you really want. You may want:

```
FOR v_iterate IN vdbtid_coll.FIRST..vdbtid_coll.LAST  
LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('The currency code is: '
        || p_failedreservation(v_iterate).currencycode);  
END LOOP;
```

which gets:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
The currency code is: USD
The currency code is: NOK
```

You don't really need the second select/collection at all though, you can do:

```
FOR v_iterate IN 1..p_failedreservation.COUNT
LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('The currency code is: '
        || p_failedreservation(v_iterate).currencycode);  
END LOOP;
```

... for the same result. Although I'm not sure what the relevance of the `debitreservationid` is in that second query, as it is the same value (1) in both rows.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to select multiple rows into a collection. You need to use `BULK COLLECT INTO` rather than just `INTO`.

Change

```
SELECT frs.debitreservationid
INTO vdbtid_coll
FROM TABLE(p_failedreservation) frs;
```

To

```
SELECT frs.debitreservationid
BULK COLLECT INTO vdbtid_coll
FROM TABLE(p_failedreservation) frs;
```

and you probably want the output to be:

```
FOR v_iterate IN vdbtid_coll.FIRST..vdbtid_coll.LAST LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line('The currency code is: '|| vdbtid_coll(v_iterate) );
END LOOP;
```

However, you could simplify it all to:

```
DECLARE    
    P_FAILEDRESERVATION APPDATA.TYPE_FAILEDRESERVATION_COLL;
BEGIN    
  SELECT TYPE_FAILEDRESERVATION(
           fk_transactionid,
           debitreservationid,
           reservationtime,
           reservationamount,
           currencycode,
           availableamount
         ) 
  BULK COLLECT INTO p_failedreservation
  FROM failedreservation;

  FOR v_iterate IN p_failedreservation.FIRST .. p_failedreservation.LAST LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(
      'The currency code is: '|| p_failedreservation(v_iterate).currencycode
    );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try casting the type array to its type as follows

```
SELECT frs.debitreservationid
  BULK COLLECT INTO vdbtid_coll
  FROM TABLE(CAST(p_failedreservation as APPDATA.TYPE_FAILEDRESERVATION_COLL)) frs;
```

Comment: I didn't noticed that you are taking values in collection. Do it with `bulk collect`. I have modified the answer.

Answer (score 1):

PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got CHAR

You may get this error in case you write type table in place of type object when
using BULK COLLECT INTO, i faced this error coz i did so.

FOR EXAMPLE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_TYPE AS OBJECT (NAME VARCHAR2(20));
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TBL_TYPE IS TABLE OF OBJ_TYPE;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNC1 RETURN TBL_TYPE AS
TBL_TEXT TBL_TYPE := TBL_TYPE();
BEGIN
SELECT ***OBJ_TYPE*** (NAME) BULK COLLECT INTO ***TBL_TEXT*** FROM <table-name> ;
RETURN ***TBL_TEXT***;
END;
/
```

Care should be taken when using object type and table type in the function.